# how to correctly pass array to state

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with react `setState` i want to pass to state `disciplinesArray`
in function `setArray()`. sorting goes well but array is not filtred. in console log in `setArray()` I see filtered and sort array but state is only sort.

All works until I add `setToggle()` and `setInitialArray()`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        filterType: 'all',
        sortType: 'alphabetical',
        arrayOfDisciplines: this.setInitialArray()
    }
}
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    console.log(this.state)
    if (prevState===this.state) {
        this.setState({
            disciplinesArray: this.setArray()

        })
    }
}
setInitialArray() {
    let disciplinesArray = this.props.disciplines
    disciplinesArray = disciplinesArray.map((discipline) => {
        return discipline = {
            ...discipline,
            score: disciplineScore(this.props.athlete.skillset, discipline.requirements),
            isHidden: false
        }
    })
    return disciplinesArray
}
setArray() {
    let disciplinesArray = this.state.arrayOfDisciplines
    switch (this.state.sortType) {
        case 'alphabetical':
            disciplinesArray = disciplinesArray.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
            })
            break
        case 'score':
            disciplinesArray = disciplinesArray.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.score - b.score
            })
            break
        default:


    }
    switch (this.state.filterType) {
        case 'team':
            console.log('team')
            disciplinesArray = disciplinesArray.filter((discipline) => {
                return discipline.isIndividual === false
            })
            break
        case 'individual':
            console.log('team')
            disciplinesArray = disciplinesArray.filter((discipline) => {
                return discipline.isIndividual === true
            })
            break
        default:
    }
    return disciplinesArray
}
setToggle(disciplineName, props) {
    let disciplinesArray = this.state.arrayOfDisciplined
    disciplinesArray.find((discipline) => {
        return discipline.name === disciplineName
    }).isHidden = !disciplinesArray.find((discipline) => {
        return discipline.name === disciplineName
    }).isHidden
    console.log(disciplineArray)
    return disciplinesArray

}
setSortType(e) {
    this.setState({
        sortType: e.target.value
    })
}
setFilterType(e) {
    this.setState({
        filterType: e.target.value
    })
}
}
```

I'm expecting filtered and sorted array in state

Comment: `ComponentDidUpdate` gets `prevProps` as first paramter.

Comment: Like the commentor above points out, your didUpdate gets prevProps first.  You can still get prevState if you have that as your second param

Comment: `sort` function sorts the initial array, it does not create a new array. You should use `slice().sort()`.

Comment: `setToggle` also changes the contents of the array stored inside `state`.

Comment: I actually see a lot of bugs I am not sure which one causes failed filtering.

Comment: @Sulthan could you tell me about bugs u saw?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that your code is full of small bugs. The fact that sorting works is actually a random consequence of another bug. Consider that your initial state:

```
this.state = {
    filterType: 'all',
    sortType: 'alphabetical',
    arrayOfDisciplines: this.setInitialArray()
}
```

Stores the initial array into `this.state.arrayOfDisciplines`.

When changing the value however:

```
this.setState({
   disciplinesArray: this.setArray()
})
```

You are storing that to `this.state.disciplinesArray`.

That cannot work, they should be the same.

The fact that it works is caused by another bug:

```
let disciplinesArray = this.state.arrayOfDisciplines
switch (this.state.sortType) {
    case 'alphabetical':
        disciplinesArray = disciplinesArray.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
        })
        break
```

This actually takes the reference to the array in your state, sorts that array in your `state` and stores in a local variable. Note that `Array.sort` sorts an array in-place, therefore you should usually prefix that by `slice`:

```
 disciplinesArray = disciplinesArray.slice().sort((a, b) => {
     return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
 })
```

In summary: your bug is a bad property name in `setState` and the fact that you are changing the value inside `state` directly.

The same problem can be seen also in `setToggle` function, which also modifies state directly. It should look something like this:

```
return this.state.arrayOfDisciplined
   // always create a new array, don't just update a value inside the array
   .map(discipline => {
       if (discipline.name !== disciplineName) {
          return discipline;
       } 

       // always create a new immutable object, don't mutate the old state
       return {
           ...discipline,
           isHidden: !discipline.isHidden
       };
   });
```

Comment: `let disciplinesArray = this.state.arrayOfDisciplines` Is this manipulate state directly?

Comment: @radeth Nope, but calling `disciplinesArray.sort()` does manipulate state directly unless you call `slice()`.